# How to use a thunk dispatch to create a standard promise that returns `success` or `error`

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have a toast package that receives a standard promise as an argument and does something upon `success` or `error`:

```
toast.promise(
  updateNotePromise,
  {
    loading: 'Saving...',
    success: (data: any) => 'Note saved!',
    error: (err) => err.toString()
  }
);
```

This is the promise I pass to the toast, but it returns a `<PayloadAction>` because it calls a thunk:

```
const updateNotePromise = await dispatch(
      updateNoteInFirestore({ note: noteInput, noteDocId: noteProp.docId })
    );
```

How can I return `success` or `error` from this dispatch thunk operation?

I thought of processing the returned `<PayloadAction>` by wrapping the thunk. This would be my naive approach:

```
const updateNotePromise = async(): Promise<{success: boolean | error: any}> => {
  try {
    await dispatch(updateNoteInFirestore({ note: noteInput, noteDocId: noteProp.docId
    return success }))
  }
  catch {
    (error)=> return error}
```

Am I on the right track?

Edit: here's the thunk code:

```
export const updateNoteInFirestore = createAsyncThunk(


'updateNoteInFirestore',
  async (
    { note, noteDocId }: { note: string; noteDocId?: string },
    { getState, dispatch }
  ) => {
    const poolState = (getState() as RootState).customerPool.pool;
    const userState = (getState() as RootState).user;
    const time = Timestamp.now();
    const path = noteDocId ? noteDocId : undefined;
    const message = note;
    if (poolState?.docID) {
      await notesService.updateNote(
        {
          pool: poolState.docID,
          customer: userState?.user?.uid ?? 'Undefined Customer',
          //we do not update dateFirstCreated
          ...(path ? { dateLastUpdated: time } : { dateFirstCreated: time }),
          dateLastUpdated: time,
          message: message,
          editHistory: [],
          seenByAdmin: false
        },
        path
      );
      dispatch(fetchNotesByCustomerId(userState?.user?.uid));
      return { error: false };
    }
    return { error: true };
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return an error with createAsyncThunk you can use [`rejectWithValue`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#createasyncthunk)

```js
const fetchUserById = createAsyncThunk(
  'users/fetchById',
  async (userId, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://example.com/api/stuff`)
    if (response.status === 404)
       return rejectWithValue(new Error("Impossible to do stuff"));
    return response.json()
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks Julien, I wasn’t aware of rejectWithValue

Comment: Yes this is now the recommended approach I guess to use theses tools from redux toolkit

Answer (score 1):

I think for your use case, it's better to use a promise-based function followed by a dispatch reducer action rather than an asyncThunk.

asyncThunks return value can only be consumed by builders that are defined within slice as far as I know.

You need to break your problem into three steps:

1. Creating a wrapper promiseFunction as needed by your toast.
2. Creating a promise helper function where you must be able to supply the variables `poolState` and `userState` as these variables were accessed through `getState()` in your async thunk but that isn't possible in your `promiseHelperFunction` If you define `promiseHelperFunction` within your functional component you could use `useAppSelector` to access those states. I have added the comment for the same in the `promiseHelperFunction`.
3. Now once you're done with this you can now consume `promiseFunction` in your toast.

You might need to import `fetchNotesByCustomerId` that you're using in your asyncThunk as it may not be accessible to the component where you're writing the toast implementation.

Here's the code for same:

```
const updateNotePromise = async () => {
  return updatePromiseHelperFunction({
    note: noteInput,
    noteDocId: noteProp.docId,
  });
};
const updatePromiseHelperFunction = async ({
  note,
  noteDocId,
}: {
  note: string;
  noteDocId?: string;
}) => {
  /*
  // Before the Promise you must ensure you're able to access these variables:
  const poolState = useAppSelector(state => state.customerPool.pool);
  const userState = useAppSelector(state => state.user);

*/
  const time = Timestamp.now();
  const path = noteDocId ? noteDocId : undefined;
  if (poolState?.docID) {
    await notesService.updateNote(
      {
        pool: poolState.docID,
        customer: userState?.user?.uid ?? 'Undefined Customer',
        //we do not update dateFirstCreated
        ...(path ? { dateLastUpdated: time } : { dateFirstCreated: time }),
        dateLastUpdated: time,
        message: note,
        editHistory: [],
        seenByAdmin: false,
      },
      path
    );
    dispatch(fetchNotesByCustomerId(userState?.user?.uid));
    return { error: false };
  }
  return { error: true };
};
```

Comment: Thanks @ShivamSahil, that’s a creative approach